# In a PID, every irreducible element is a prime element. What's wrong with following?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

if $p=ab$ $\implies p|ab$

If $p$ is irreducible then either $a$ or $b$ is a unit.

If $a$ is a unit, then

$a^{-1}p=b$

or, $b \in <p>$
$ \implies b=pt \implies p|b$

Thus $p$ is prime

Something must be wrong here because I didn't use the fact that given ring is a principal ideal domain.

Comment: What do *you think* is the definition of irreducible element in a ring? Because it looks like you assumed $\;p\;$ is irreduxible in what you did above...yet the second line confuses me.\

Comment: The issue with your proof is that you say $p=ab$. The condition for primality is that for any $a,b$ such that $p\mid ab$, not $p=ab$.

Comment: @DonThousand but $p=ab$ should imply that $p|ab$

Comment: @tatha true, not the other way around though.

Comment: @DonAntonio it is asked that every irreducible element is a prime element in PID. So i started with a irreducible element $p$.

Comment: @tatha The irreducible element is $p$, i.e. it is an element which satisfies the condition that $p\ne0$ and, for all $a,b$ such that $p=ab$, either $a$ is a unit or $b$ is, but not both of them. You want to prove that $p$ is prime, i.e. that, for all $c$,$d$ such that $p$ divides $cd$, $p$ divides either $c$ or $d$.

Comment: @DonThousand I thinnk I got it. It is limited to elements where $ p=ab$ and not oter elements where $p|ab$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b\in R$. You need to assume that $p\mid ab$ and $p\nmid a$ and then show that $p\mid b$. How do you do this?
The correct prove is [here](https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Irreducible_implies_prime_(PID)), have a look.

Comment: In the proof you gave, why the fact that $p$ is irreducible implies that $(p,a)=(1)$ ? suppose there is $k\neq 1$ s.t. $(p,a)=(k)$, i.e. there is $k=xp+ya$. I can't get a contradiction from here. Could you help ?

Comment: @Dietrich So what you are saying that I didn't take $p|ab$ assumption. But doesn't $p=ab$ imply that $p|ab$.

Comment: tatha: again, the definition of primality requires us to start with $p\mid cd$ for two arbitary elements $c,d\in R$. This has nothing to do with $p=ab$ from irreducibility.

Comment: We have to prove that every irreducible element is a prime in PID. So I started with definition of irreducibility. But i think you are suggesting that this is only limited to cases where $p=ab$ and not others.

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you confuse the notation. We have two different definitions and if it helps, write different letters, e.g., $p=ab$ for irreduicbilty and $p\mid cd$ for primality.